# How can I do this blurring effect on a shape in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

I would like to reach the same effect on the sides of a simple polygon, as this below image shows:

[image]

I have created a shape in PS, and it has some kind of "semi-transparent" edges, but not like this.

How can I get this effect?

[image]

Based on @wolff suggestion I have added the *Gaussian blur* to a copy of the shape, but somehow it's still different:

[image]

Mine is the bottom one, 180 degree rotated. Please see the original is having gray colored edges, while mine with the Gaussian blur doesn't.

Comment: The gray is because it was originally on white background and is badly cut out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semi-transparency you see along the edge of the shape you have drawn is called *anti-aliasing*.

By default, many tools in Photoshop applies anti-aliasing to make edges seem less jagged.

For example when making a selection using the *Polygonal Lasso Tool* you can enable or disable anti-aliasing in the *Options* panel in the top of the screen.

[image]

The shape you are trying to match seems to have additional blurring applied.

After drawing your shape on a separate layer, try applying some *Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur* and adjust the *Radius* until you have the same effect.

[image]

Note that it isn't given that you can always find a blur radius which will match perfectly. The image you are trying to match might have been manipulated in several different ways (scaling, blurring, sharpening, levels etc.).

Comment: Kind of close, thank you! I have updated the question, becuase I like learning. There are grayish pixels at the edges of the original which Gaussian blur doesn't give me. Although I'm quite satisfied with the current result, It would be great if we could finetune this. Question is updated.

Comment: @Daniel, hmmm as I said, it can be almost impossible to know what manipulation an image has gone through. Those grayish pixels could come from so many things. Including being scaled or compressed. Depending on what you need to do with this image, it might be easier to start from scratch. But could you at at least post the original PNG at its actual size (or a crop of it), so it's easier to work with? Had to scale your screenshots down before with some loss in colors.

Comment: It looks like a different filter than gaussian. Maybe box blur or different transfer curve